Flutter: StateError (Bad state: No ProviderScope found)
i am trying to have both dark and light mode (before my app was just dark).
i used hooks_riverpod: ^2.5.1 to switch between these modes.
when i debug, i found that it throw StateError (Bad state: No ProviderScope found) because the scope is null (in static ProviderContainer containerOf inside freamework.dart file).
my main file:
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:video_app/app_theme.dart';
import 'package:video_app/theme_provider.dart';

import 'JoinScreen.dart';
import 'signallingService.dart';

void main() {
  // start videoCall app
   runApp(VideoCallApp());
 }

class VideoCallApp extends HookConsumerWidget {
  VideoCallApp({super.key});

  // signalling server url
  final String websocketUrl2 = "http://10.0.2.2:8000"; //for emulator
  final String websocketUrl = "http://localhost:8000";
  final String websocketUrl3 = "http://192.5.10.8:8000";

   final String selfCallerID =
      Random().nextInt(999999).toString().padLeft(6, '0');
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final appThemeState = ref.watch(appThemeStateNotifier);
    SignallingService.instance.init(
      websocketUrl: websocketUrl,
      websocketUrl2: websocketUrl2,
      websocketUrl3: websocketUrl3,
      selfCallerID: selfCallerID,
    );
     return MaterialApp(
      darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
      themeMode:
          appThemeState.isDarkModeEnable ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
      home: JoinScreen(selfCallerId: selfCallerID),
    );
  }
}

and my appThemeState file:
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
final appThemeStateNotifier = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => AppThemeState());

class AppThemeState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var isDarkModeEnable = true;

  void setLightTheme() {
    isDarkModeEnable = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void setDarkTheme() {
    isDarkModeEnable = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}


For providers to work, you must add ProviderScope at the root of your Flutter applications:
void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: VideoCallApp()));
}

